# I need to add make my navigation arrows shift images

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, css

Hi i need my nav arrows to shift images to and fro in my automatic slideshow, my java script is so clumsy it doesn't work, slide show is CSS based, am trying to use javascript on the arrows to move them temporarily untill slideshow resumes.

```js
var main = function() {

  var paused = false

  $('.arrow-right').click(function() {
    paused = true;
    $('.slide-main > div:first')
      .next()
      .end()
      .appendTo('#slideshow');
  });

  $('.arrow-left').click(function() {
    paused = true;
    $('.slide-main > div:last')
      .prependTo('#slideshow')
      .next()
      .end();
  });


};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 512px;
  margin: 0;
}
.slide-container {
  height: 512px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slide-main {
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: 30s slide infinite;
}
.slide {
  height: 512px;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  45% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  90% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  95% {
    left: -400%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0%;
  }
}
.arrow {} .arrow-left {
  padding: 20px;
}
.arrow-left:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 42%;
  left: 3%;
  height: 9%;
  width: 2%;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: skew(135deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(135deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(135deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(135deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(135deg, 0deg);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  opacity: .4;
}
.arrow-left:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 51%;
  left: 3%;
  right: 60%;
  height: 9%;
  width: 2%;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-130deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-135deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-135deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-135deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(-135deg, 0deg);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  opacity: .4;
}
​ .arrow-right {
  padding: 20px;
}
.arrow-right:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 42%;
  left: 95%;
  height: 9%;
  width: 2%;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: skew(45deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(45deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(45deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(45deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(45deg, 0deg);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  opacity: .4;
}
.arrow-right:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 51%;
  left: 95%;
  height: 9%;
  width: 2%;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-45deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-45deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(-45deg, 0deg);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  opacity: .4;
}
​ .arrow-left:hover:before {
  box-shadow: 8px 1px 1px gray;
  opacity: 10;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.arrow-left:hover:before {
  box-shadow: 8px 1px 1px gray;
  opacity: 10;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.arrow-left:hover:after {
  box-shadow: 8px 1px 1px gray;
  opacity: 10;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.arrow-right:hover:before {
  box-shadow: -8px 1px 1px gray;
  opacity: 10;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.arrow-right:hover:after {
  box-shadow: -8px 1px 1px gray;
  opacity: 10;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!--start-->
<div class="slide-container">
  <div class="slide-main">
    <img src="images/prop3.jpg" alt="" class="slide" />
    <img src="images/cover.jpg" alt="" class="slide" />
    <img src="images/cover2.jpg" alt="" class="slide" />
    <img src="images/drinkss.jpg" alt="" class="slide" />
    <img src="images/collection.jpg" alt="" class="slide" />
  </div>
</div>


<!--end-->
<div class="heacontai">
  <a class="arrow-left" role="button"></a>

  <a class="arrow-right" role="button"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: You coudl use[Slick Carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) instead of building your own. It is pretty customizable & feature rich.

Comment: i checked Slick Carousel out, it pretty good. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var main = function() {

  var paused = false

  $('.arrow-right').click(function() {
    paused = true;    
    $('.slide-main :first-child')     
      .detach()
      .appendTo('.slide-main');
  });

  $('.arrow-left').click(function() {
    paused = true;
    $('.slide-main :last-child')
      .detach()
      .prependTo('.slide-main')      
  });


};

$(document).ready(main);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 512px;
  margin: 0;
}
.slide-container {
  height: 512px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slide-main {
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: 10s slide infinite;
}
.slide {
  height: 512px;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  45% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  90% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  95% {
    left: -400%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0%;
  }
}
.arrow {} .arrow-left {
  padding: 20px;
}
.arrow-left:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 42%;
  left: 3%;
  height: 9%;
  width: 2%;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: skew(135deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(135deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(135deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(135deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(135deg, 0deg);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  opacity: .4;
}
.arrow-left:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 51%;
  left: 3%;
  right: 60%;
  height: 9%;
  width: 2%;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-130deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-135deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-135deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-135deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(-135deg, 0deg);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  opacity: .4;
}
​ .arrow-right {
  padding: 20px;
}
.arrow-right:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 42%;
  left: 95%;
  height: 9%;
  width: 2%;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: skew(45deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(45deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(45deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(45deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(45deg, 0deg);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  opacity: .4;
}
.arrow-right:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 51%;
  left: 95%;
  height: 9%;
  width: 2%;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-45deg, 0deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-45deg, 0deg);
  transform: skew(-45deg, 0deg);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  opacity: .4;
}
​ .arrow-left:hover:before {
  box-shadow: 8px 1px 1px gray;
  opacity: 10;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.arrow-left:hover:before {
  box-shadow: 8px 1px 1px gray;
  opacity: 10;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.arrow-left:hover:after {
  box-shadow: 8px 1px 1px gray;
  opacity: 10;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.arrow-right:hover:before {
  box-shadow: -8px 1px 1px gray;
  opacity: 10;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.arrow-right:hover:after {
  box-shadow: -8px 1px 1px gray;
  opacity: 10;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--start-->
<div class="slide-container">
  <div class="slide-main">
    <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/a31/colorful-umbrella-1176220.jpg" alt="" class="slide" />
    <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/924/toe-socks-1258857.jpg" alt="" class="slide" />
    <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/1d2/music-nightclub-1420666.jpg" class="slide">  
    <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/71d/pink-math-function-1170075.jpg" class="slide">
    <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/651/leaf-1170355.jpg" class="slide">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!--end-->
<div class="heacontai">
  <a class="arrow-left" role="button"></a>

  <a class="arrow-right" role="button"></a>
</div>
```

it seems to work